# Can't Save Keras Model with custom layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I'm trying to save my Keras model, but I always get the error (Complete stack at the end of the post):

> ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)

Here is my Code for the Network:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class SwinTransformerKeras(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        dim,
        name,
        num_patch,
        num_heads,
        window_size=7,
        shift_size=0,
        num_mlp=1024,
        qkv_bias=True,
        dropout_rate=0.0,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.dim = dim  # number of input dimensions
        self.num_patch = num_patch  # number of embedded patches
        self.num_heads = num_heads  # number of attention heads
        self.window_size = window_size  # size of window
        self.shift_size = shift_size  # size of window shift
        self.num_mlp = num_mlp  # number of MLP nodes
        self.qkv_bias = qkv_bias
        self.dropout_rate=dropout_rate
        self.name1=name

        self.norm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-5, name=name+"_norm1")
        self.attn = WindowAttentionKeras(
            dim,
            name,
            window_size=(self.window_size, self.window_size),
            num_heads=num_heads,
            qkv_bias=qkv_bias,
            dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
        )
        self.drop_path = DropPath(dropout_rate, name=name+"_drop1")
        self.norm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-5, name=name+"_norm2")

        self.mlp = keras.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Dense(num_mlp, name=name+"_dense1"),
                layers.Activation(keras.activations.gelu, name=name+"_gelu1"),
                layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name=name+"_drop2"),
                layers.Dense(dim, name=name+"_norm3"),
                layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name=name+"_drop3"),
            ]
        )

        if min(self.num_patch) < self.window_size:
            self.shift_size = 0
            self.window_size = min(self.num_patch)
            
    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'dim': self.dim,
            'num_patch': self.num_patch,
            'num_heads': self.num_heads,
            'window_size': self.window_size,
            'shift_size': self.shift_size,
            'num_mlp': self.num_mlp,
            'qkv_bias': self.qkv_bias,
            'dropout_rate': self.dropout_rate,
            'name1':self.name1
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config, **config}
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        if self.shift_size == 0:
            self.attn_mask = None
        else:
            height, width = self.num_patch
            h_slices = (
                slice(0, -self.window_size),
                slice(-self.window_size, -self.shift_size),
                slice(-self.shift_size, None),
            )
            w_slices = (
                slice(0, -self.window_size),
                slice(-self.window_size, -self.shift_size),
                slice(-self.shift_size, None),
            )
            mask_array = np.zeros((1, height, width, 1))
            count = 0
            for h in h_slices:
                for w in w_slices:
                    mask_array[:, h, w, :] = count
                    count += 1
            mask_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(mask_array)

            # mask array to windows
            mask_windows = window_partition(mask_array, self.window_size)
            mask_windows = tf.reshape(
                mask_windows, shape=[-1, self.window_size * self.window_size]
            )
            attn_mask = tf.expand_dims(mask_windows, axis=1) - tf.expand_dims(
                mask_windows, axis=2
            )
            attn_mask = tf.where(attn_mask != 0, -100.0, attn_mask)
            attn_mask = tf.where(attn_mask == 0, 0.0, attn_mask)
            self.attn_mask = tf.Variable(initial_value=attn_mask, trainable=False)

    def call(self, x):
        height, width = self.num_patch
        _, num_patches_before, channels = x.shape
        x_skip = x
        x = self.norm1(x)
        x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, height, width, channels))
        if self.shift_size > 0:
            shifted_x = tf.roll(
                x, shift=[-self.shift_size, -self.shift_size], axis=[1, 2]
            )
        else:
            shifted_x = x

        x_windows = window_partition(shifted_x, self.window_size)
        x_windows = tf.reshape(
            x_windows, shape=(-1, self.window_size * self.window_size, channels)
        )
        attn_windows = self.attn(x_windows, mask=self.attn_mask)

        attn_windows = tf.reshape(
            attn_windows, shape=(-1, self.window_size, self.window_size, channels)
        )
        shifted_x = window_reverse(
            attn_windows, self.window_size, height, width, channels
        )
        if self.shift_size > 0:
            x = tf.roll(
                shifted_x, shift=[self.shift_size, self.shift_size], axis=[1, 2]
            )
        else:
            x = shifted_x

        x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, height * width, channels))
        x = self.drop_path(x)
        x = x_skip + x
        x_skip = x
        x = self.norm2(x)
        x = self.mlp(x)
        x = self.drop_path(x)
        x = x_skip + x
        return x



def window_partition(x, window_size):
    _, height, width, channels = x.shape
    patch_num_y = height // window_size
    patch_num_x = width // window_size
    x = tf.reshape(
        x, shape=(-1, patch_num_y, window_size, patch_num_x, window_size, channels)
    )
    x = tf.transpose(x, (0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5))
    windows = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, window_size, window_size, channels))
    return windows


def window_reverse(windows, window_size, height, width, channels):
    patch_num_y = height // window_size
    patch_num_x = width // window_size
    x = tf.reshape(
        windows,
        shape=(-1, patch_num_y, patch_num_x, window_size, window_size, channels),
    )
    x = tf.transpose(x, perm=(0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5))
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, height, width, channels))
    return x


class DropPath(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, drop_prob=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.drop_prob = drop_prob

    def call(self, x):
        input_shape = tf.shape(x)
        batch_size = input_shape[0]
        rank = x.shape.rank
        shape = (batch_size,) + (1,) * (rank - 1)
        random_tensor = (1 - self.drop_prob) + tf.random.uniform(shape, dtype=x.dtype)
        path_mask = tf.floor(random_tensor)
        output = tf.math.divide(x, 1 - self.drop_prob) * path_mask
        return output


class WindowAttentionKeras(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(
        self, dim, name, window_size, num_heads, qkv_bias=True, dropout_rate=0.0, **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dim = dim
        self.name1=name
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.scale = (dim // num_heads) ** -0.5
        self.qkv = layers.Dense(dim * 3, use_bias=qkv_bias, name=name+"attn_qkv")
        self.dropout = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name=name+"attn_drop")
        self.proj = layers.Dense(dim, name=name+"attn_dim")

    def build(self, input_shape):
        num_window_elements = (2 * self.window_size[0] - 1) * (
            2 * self.window_size[1] - 1
        )
        self.relative_position_bias_table = self.add_weight(
            shape=(num_window_elements, self.num_heads),
            initializer=tf.initializers.Zeros(),
            trainable=True,
        )
        coords_h = np.arange(self.window_size[0])
        coords_w = np.arange(self.window_size[1])
        coords_matrix = np.meshgrid(coords_h, coords_w, indexing="ij")
        coords = np.stack(coords_matrix)
        coords_flatten = coords.reshape(2, -1)
        relative_coords = coords_flatten[:, :, None] - coords_flatten[:, None, :]
        relative_coords = relative_coords.transpose([1, 2, 0])
        relative_coords[:, :, 0] += self.window_size[0] - 1
        relative_coords[:, :, 1] += self.window_size[1] - 1
        relative_coords[:, :, 0] *= 2 * self.window_size[1] - 1
        relative_position_index = relative_coords.sum(-1)

        self.relative_position_index = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=tf.convert_to_tensor(relative_position_index), trainable=False
        )

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        _, size, channels = x.shape
        head_dim = channels // self.num_heads
        
        x_qkv = self.qkv(x)
        x_qkv = tf.reshape(x_qkv, shape=(-1, size, 3, self.num_heads, head_dim))
        x_qkv = tf.transpose(x_qkv, perm=(2, 0, 3, 1, 4))
        q, k, v = x_qkv[0], x_qkv[1], x_qkv[2]
        q = q * self.scale
        k = tf.transpose(k, perm=(0, 1, 3, 2))
        attn = q @ k

        num_window_elements = self.window_size[0] * self.window_size[1]
        relative_position_index_flat = tf.reshape(
            self.relative_position_index, shape=(-1,)
        )
        relative_position_bias = tf.gather(
            self.relative_position_bias_table, relative_position_index_flat
        )
        relative_position_bias = tf.reshape(
            relative_position_bias, shape=(num_window_elements, num_window_elements, -1)
        )
        relative_position_bias = tf.transpose(relative_position_bias, perm=(2, 0, 1))
        attn = attn + tf.expand_dims(relative_position_bias, axis=0)

        if mask is not None:
            nW = mask.get_shape()[0]
            mask_float = tf.cast(
                tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(mask, axis=1), axis=0), tf.float32
            )
            attn = (
                tf.reshape(attn, shape=(-1, nW, self.num_heads, size, size))
                + mask_float
            )
            attn = tf.reshape(attn, shape=(-1, self.num_heads, size, size))
            attn = keras.activations.softmax(attn, axis=-1)
        else:
            attn = keras.activations.softmax(attn, axis=-1)
        attn = self.dropout(attn)

        x_qkv = attn @ v
        x_qkv = tf.transpose(x_qkv, perm=(0, 2, 1, 3))
        x_qkv = tf.reshape(x_qkv, shape=(-1, size, channels))
        x_qkv = self.proj(x_qkv)
        x_qkv = self.dropout(x_qkv)
        return x_qkv
```

Here is my code when I try to save:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model


inputs = layers.Input(shape=(3136, 96))  

x = SwinTransformerKeras(dim=96, 
                name="STK1",
                num_patch=(56, 56),
                num_heads=3,
                window_size=7,
                shift_size=0,
                num_mlp = 284,
                qkv_bias = True
               )(inputs)

model_keras = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model_keras.save("tmp.h5")
```

And the error I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 17>()
      6 x = SwinTransformerKeras(dim=96, 
      7                 name="STK1",
      8                 num_patch=(56, 56),
   (...)
     13                 qkv_bias = True
     14                )(inputs)
     16 model_keras = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
---> 17 model_keras.save("tmp.h5")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py:161, in Group.create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    158         parent_path, name = name.rsplit(b'/', 1)
    159         group = self.require_group(parent_path)
--> 161 dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, **kwds)
    162 dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
    163 return dset

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py:156, in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, name, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times, external, track_order, dcpl, dapl, efile_prefix, virtual_prefix, allow_unknown_filter)
    152 else:
    153     sid = h5s.create_simple(shape, maxshape)
--> 156 dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl, dapl=dapl)
    158 if (data is not None) and (not isinstance(data, Empty)):
    159     dset_id.write(h5s.ALL, h5s.ALL, data)

File h5py/_objects.pyx:54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py/_objects.pyx:55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py/h5d.pyx:87, in h5py.h5d.create()

ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)
```

Most of the code if from: https://keras.io/examples/vision/swin_transformers/

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hi @Adrien Nivaggioli, Please try again by installing the h5py package using `pip install h5py` in your system before saving the model or you can try again by changing the name of the save model. Please have a look at the link [How to Save and load Keras models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) for your reference.